# Repositioning controls when the orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, screen-orientation, autolayout

I know Auto Layout can be used to make the sizes and position consistent when the orientation changes. Is it possible to completely change the layout when the orientation changes?

For example, please look at the below wire-frame of a simple login screen in portrait mode.

[image]

Now if I rotate the device, I want to completely re-position the controls.

[image]

Can this kind of a thing be done by using Auto Layout? If not, how should I go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Ya its possible. but you have to manually reset the frame of each UI controls when orientation changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case it can be achieved by two methods, instead of reframing every component you can group the controls like the following..

1. Parent View -> User Info View -> All User Info controls.. By doing this you will have to just reframe the **User Info View** not all the controls..

   Then only Logo and Company name left to reframe.. Total 3 controls to reframe if you group your controls..
2. Create two views one for Portrait and other for Landscape mode, and just add and remove on rotations.. this is the fastest way as you won't have to readjust the frame by tedious code.

Hope above helps.

Comment: Do I have to turn off Auto Layout when using either of these methods?

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention in my question was that I'm using storyboards. In a storyboard scene, you cannot insert 2 views into 1 UIViewController, right? What should I do then?

Comment: How does ur solution 1 work with storyboards? how to group exactly?

Answer (score 4):

you cant set frames differently : -

```
-(void)setFramesForPotrait
{

// set frames here

}

-(void)setFramesForLandscaeMode
{

// set frames here

}

-(bool)shouldAutorotate.....
{
return Yes
}

-()willAutoRotate......
{
if(orientation = uiinterfaceOrientationPotrait)
{
[self setFramesForPotrait];
}
else
{
[self setFramesForLandscape];
}
```

Comment: +1: Nice code alternative to having two views within a nib : D

Comment: wht do u mean by this comment??

Comment: See @iphonic 's answer... number (2) explains the option that I've seen in other places as an alternative using two views... However, for a pure code approach, I like yours better

Comment: This is fine if you're not using layout constraints. If you are using them, you shouldn't be setting frames at all, you should be modifying constraints.

Comment: Do I have to turn off Auto Layout when using this?

Comment: I see. If I manually position the controls programatically, would that be an issue when it comes to running in say iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 since iPhone 5 is longer than the rest of the iPhone models?

Comment: wht do u mean by manually position the controls programatically?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make any sense. What I meant was if I position the controls through code using your method.

Comment: @Sydney Still working on it, man.. I'm researching more on Frames and all

Comment: @Isuru  Wht are u searching on frames?

Comment: While your answer was good and valid, I thought of going ahead with the iphonic second method because positioning controls using code is a bit too overwhelming for a guy with just 1 month of iOS dev experience. But thank you. In the future I might hopefully revert to this method because I dont feel comfortable maintaining 2 layouts for each screen.

Comment: thats ok its fine but wont u have memory problems when u use that method.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and here's what I've found so far.
The approach I'm using is having two sets (potentially multiple) sets of constraints for different screen sizes or orientations. So I just design for portrait and connect all constraints that are portrait-specific to a IBOutletCollection:
[image]
Then switch the VC orientation in InterfaceBuilder to Landscape and add the required constraints for this orientation and connect to the corresponding outlet:
[image]

Then in code I'm removing or adding the constraints as required:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self updateViewConstraints];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    if (self.view.frame.size.width >= kSize * 2 + kPadding * 3)
    {
        [self.view removeConstraints:self.constraintsForPortrait];
        [self.view addConstraints:self.constraintsForLandscape];
    } else
    {
        [self.view removeConstraints:self.constraintsForLandscape];
        [self.view addConstraints:self.constraintsForPortrait];
    }
}
```

You can achieve similar results with this code, basing your adding/removing of constraints on orientation instead of frame size:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self updateViewConstraints];
}
```

But keeping in mind that Apple is rumored to release devices with different screen aspect ratios and obsoleting the UIInterfaceOrientation and rotation events, it might be worth preparing in advance.
Will see what future brings.

The downside of the approach is that that Xcode will be complaining about the design being ambiguous, which it actually is, since Xcode doesn't know we'll be removing the ambiguity at runtime. To tackle that you could set the priority of the constraints to be optional for all other orientations that you're not designing for at this particular moment (e.g. if you're designing for Portrait then optionalize the constraints for Landscape).

Comment: P.S.: on more complex screens this becomes such a bloody mess!

Answer (score 0):

When using autolayout you can **override updateViewConstraints** to modify the layout on orientation change:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints{

  [super updateViewConstraints];
  //portrait
  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){

  }
  //landscape
  else{
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: i've read that too, specifically "when using auto layout". i'm not using xibs for my layouts. how does the framework know that i'm using auto layout?

Comment: @tote: As I know auto layout is always there. Your spring and struts configuration will be translated to auto layout by the system.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with layout constraints something like I have below. This doesn't quite work, because your sketch doesn't quite work -- your landscape view is too long compared with what you really get in landscape. You would have to shorten the login text fields for everything to fit, but this should give you an idea how it's done. The buttonWidth constraint shows how to have a negative correlation between the width of the view and the width of a button -- that is, the button's width will be less in landscape than in portrait. I have several IBOutlets to constraints that I reference in the code. I can describe them for you if you're interested, but I'll just throw this out there for now:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonWidth;
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *logoTop;
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *logoAlignToLabel;
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *logoSpaceToLabel;
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *coNameToButtonAlignment;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;
    IBOutlet UILabel *coName;
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2;
    NSArray *cons1;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [b removeConstraint:buttonWidth];
    buttonWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:b attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:-.2193 constant:350];
    [self.view addConstraint:buttonWidth];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        if (con2 != nil) {
            [self.view removeConstraints:cons1];
            [self.view removeConstraint:con2];
            [self.view addConstraints:@[logoAlignToLabel,logoSpaceToLabel,logoTop,coNameToButtonAlignment]];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
        [self.view removeConstraints:@[logoAlignToLabel,logoSpaceToLabel,logoTop,coNameToButtonAlignment]];
        cons1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-8-[logo]-4-[coName]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:0 views:@{@"logo":logo, @"coName":coName}];
        con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
        [self.view addConstraints:cons1];
        [self.view addConstraint:con2];
    }
}
```

On rotation the logo and company name label have their constraints removed, and new ones put in place. The new constraint for the button, that I put on in viewDidLoad, takes care of rotation automatically, so I don't have to adjust it at all during the rotation.

Comment: Actually, this works pretty well if the logo is small enough, and the company name short enough.