# Change autolayout orientation storyboards

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I need some help regarding the following.

Currently in my app I have a screen that reproduces audio files, the current layout shows a thumbnail at the top of the screen plus playback controls at the bottom. Now when it's rotated to landscape mode, the image should not stretch and the bottom controls should jump to the right of it. How could I do this using Autolayout? Do you know any example of something similar done programatically by adding/removing contraints where I can guide?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929207/repositioning-controls-when-the-orientation-changes this question is similar to yours.